# I've a small problem with this matrix (to find the determinant)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Find the following determinant. $$\det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 4 & -2 \\ 2 & -1 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Theoretically I know how to find the determinant of a $m \times n$ matrix, as follow:

1. Gaussian elimination,
2. Laplace method,
3. Gaussian elimination + Laplace method,
4. Sarrus's rule (this method is valid only for $3 \times 3$ matrix),
5. $2 \times 2$ matrix (easiest way).

I used the 3rd method (because if I had used only the second one, it would have  be a long and tedious process).

here's my attempt to solve it:

1. I reduced the matrix using Gaussian elimination and the result is as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 4 & -2 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 & -5 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$
This is enough in order to compute the determinant of this matrix, using the first column.

2. I used Laplace method and here's what I got:
   $$(-1)^2 \det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & -2\\ -1 & -1 & 2\\ -1 & -5 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

My result (using Sarrus's rule to compute the determinant of the minor) is 6, but the exercise has these possible solutions:

(1) -7

(2) 0

(3) 7

(4) 5

Comment: You must be the only one who can compute the determinant of a non-square matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(3,4)$ entry of your matrix after step $1$ should be a $3$.

Comment: do you mean that step 2 was wrong?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini Error carried forward.

Comment: Ah, so the gaussian elimination was wrong, 
Here is what I did: 
-2*R3 + R3 --> R3, 
-2*R4 + R4 --> R4. 
Ah, now I saw the error. Thanks